# How can I return true/false from an animation queue thats inside a click() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems so tricky to me that I think I am overlooking something simple here. 
Can you help me find it?

Basically, the situation is this 
(variables where the name is not important are named with a capital letter)  :

```
$('a').filter('somecriteria').each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    self.click(function() {
        B.animate({ something: somevalue }, { duration: "fast", complete: function(){
                return true; // <--- see notes below 
            }  
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Notes: 
How can I let this `return` be the `return` that is sent from `click()` so that the user is taken to the new page only after animate() has fully completed (NB: in my real code I have three animate()'s chained together). 
I need to do this because the animation is cut off and the new page is loaded prematurely. The animation only comes to full effect when return false is sent from click() until the animation really ends.

I tried capturing the `href` attribute of the link and doing a `window.location = capturedlink` instead of `return true`. 
This works, but if possible I want to avoid that because some people have disabled changing location because of security concerns.

Or is there another way of keeping jQuery changing to a new URL in the middle of an animation?

Thank you very much for checking out this question.

Andre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid capturing the `href` way would be the most obvious way of doing what you want. I am not sure if doing the following would circumvent people that disabled changing location in their security settings, but you could try it:

```
$('a').filter('somecriteria').each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    self.click(function() {
        if(self.hasClass('animated')) return true; // return true if already animated
        B.animate({ something: somevalue }, { duration: "fast", complete: function(){
                self.addClass('animated').click(); // fire the click event
            }  
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I can see that this should theoretically work and addind a status class is a neat trick which I couldnt think of earlier. But somehow the click() event doesnt fire. I made sure through logging that self really is an A element. Thanks for taking the time to reply. Much appreciated! :)

Comment: If self.click(); didn't work try self.trigger('click'); but I don't think it should make a difference. I am going to try this myself and see what's up...

Comment: I guess it has to do with self being the wrong kind of object... that's just a guess though. I wish I could post the full source but I am not allowed to since the page isnt live yet. `console.debug("%o", self)` returns `[a index.html]` in Firebug. So being a jQuery set should suffice for click()...

Comment: How about this. Remove the if(self.hasClass('animated')) return true; line, and replace this line self.addClass('animated').click(); with this: self.unbind('click');

Comment: well, it seems that changing window.location is the only way to have jQuery run an animation queue before chaning the page. I also tried custom event handlers together with trigger(), setInterval/setTimeout to listen for the animation queue's returning state change but it became too complicated...